# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSLContext'

Tags: python, flask

When I use `flask run`, I got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xuye/anaconda/bin/flask", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/xuye/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 894, in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "/Users/xuye/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 557, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xuye/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/xuye/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1135, in invoke
    sub_ctx = cmd.make_context(cmd_name, args, parent=ctx)
  File "/Users/xuye/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 641, in make_context
    self.parse_args(ctx, args)
  File "/Users/xuye/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 940, in parse_args
    value, args = param.handle_parse_result(ctx, opts, args)
  File "/Users/xuye/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1477, in handle_parse_result
    self.callback, ctx, self, value)
  File "/Users/xuye/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 96, in invoke_param_callback
    return callback(ctx, param, value)
  File "/Users/xuye/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 693, in _validate_key
    is_context = isinstance(cert, ssl.SSLContext)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSLContext'
```

I have searched and updated my Python version to 2.7.15 but it does not work.

Comment: BTW, i can run my flask app via pycharm, but there seems something wrong with `flask run`

Comment: something wrong with my environment. I reinstalled python and flask.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, and I think that was that I installed flask and MarkupSafe (an upgrade was needed) with the virtual environment activated. What I did to solve it was uninstall flask and MarkupSafe with the venv activated, close cmd, in a new terminal install flask and Markupsafe again and then activate the virtual environment. That worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error when using Anaconda (latest Apr 2020 on Python3) and a virtual environment. To get rid of the error:

1. Close the current terminal
2. Open Anaconda Prompt with a conda environment activated.
3. Navigate to your desired virtual environment venv/Scripts

   cd .../myvenv/Scripts
4. Activate your virtual environment

   activate
5. Re-run flask run

   flask run

Answer (score 0):

choose anaconda as the virtual environment in the project interpreter worked for me, also  i removed and flask from anaconda files